# Export fitted data of FindFit

Tags: export, fitting

I want to export the data of a FindFit in a .txt-file to do some postprocessing.

My fit is:

```
fit6 = FindFit[data, {Subscript[model, JCA], 1 < \[Alpha] < 4,1*10^-5 < Subscript[\[Lambda], th] < 1*10^-3,1*10^-5 < Subscript[\[Lambda], vis] <1*10^-3}, {{Subscript[\[Lambda], vis], 1*10^-6}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], th],1*10^-6}, \[Alpha]}, f, MaxIterations -> 100000]
```

I get something like this:
[image]

The blue curves are my experimental data and the red curve is the fitted function.

And now I want to export the calculated data (x,y-values) of the fitted red curve as a .txt-file.
How do I get these values?

EDIT: I add my model and corresponding parameters and FindFit

some parameters:

```
T0 = 21;    
P0 = 104500;  
HR = 60;    
kappla = 0.026; 
T = T0 + 273.16;
Pr = 0.71;   
R = 287.031; 
Rvp = 461.521;  
Pvp = 0.0658*T^3 - 53.7558*T^2 + 14703.8127*T - 1345485.0465;
\[Eta] = -5.95238*10^-11*T^2 + 2.71368*10^-14*T^3 + 
   7.72488*10^-8*T;  (*Viskosität von Luft in [Pa/s]*)
Cp = 4168.8*(-6.46128*10^-11*T^3 + 1.69194*10^-7*T^2 - 
     7.55179*10^-5*T + 0.249679);
Cv = Cp - R;   
\[Gamma] = Cp/Cv; 
\[Rho]0 = P0/(R*T) - (1/((R - 1)*Rvp))*(HR/100)*(Pvp/T);
c0 = (\[Gamma]*P0/\[Rho]0)^0.5 ;
kair = \[Omega]/c0;   
Z0 = \[Rho]0*c0; 
\[Omega] := 2*Pi*f; 
d = 24*10^-3;
\[Sigma] = 70000;
\[Phi] = 0.989;
```

model:

```
Reff = \[Rho]0 \[Alpha] (1 + ((\[Phi] \[Sigma]) Sqrt[
      1 + (I (4 \[Omega] \[Rho]0 \[Eta] \[Alpha]^2))/(\[Sigma]^2 \
\[Phi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(vis\), \(2\)]\))])/(
     I (\[Omega] \[Rho]0 \[Alpha])));
Keff = (P0 \[Gamma])/(\[Gamma] - (\[Gamma] - 1)/(
   1 + (8 \[Eta] Sqrt[1 + (I (\[Omega] Pr \[Rho]0 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(th\), \(2\)]\)))/(
      16 \[Eta])])/(I (\[Omega] Pr 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(th\), \(2\)]\) \[Rho]0))));
kw = \[Omega] Sqrt[Reff/Keff];
Zc = Sqrt[Reff Keff];
Zs = -((I Zc Cot[kw d])/Z0);
r = (Zs - 1)/(Zs + 1);
model = abs1 = 1 - Abs[r]^2;
```

Fit:

```
fit1 = FindFit[
  data, {model, 1 < \[Alpha] < 4, 
   1*10^-5 < Subscript[\[Lambda], th] < 1*10^-3, 
   1*10^-5 < Subscript[\[Lambda], vis] < 
    1*10^-3}, {{Subscript[\[Lambda], vis], 
    1*10^-6}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], th], 1*10^-6}, \[Alpha]}, f, 
  MaxIterations -> 100000]
Show[Plot[
  Labeled[Subscript[model, Daimler] /. fit1, "Daimler"], {f, 200, 
   8000}, PlotRange -> {{200, 7500}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListPlot[Labeled[data, "import"], 
  PlotRange -> {{200, 7500}, {0, 1}}]]
```

Extraction of my data (x,y):

{00143.7500 0000.0793
00487.5000  0000.2002
00831.2500  0000.5153
01175.0000  0000.8803
01518.7500  0000.9933
01862.5000  0000.9361
02206.2500  0000.8575
02550.0000  0000.8051
02893.7500  0000.7677
03237.5000  0000.7691
03581.2500  0000.7717
03925.0000  0000.7945
04268.7500  0000.8263
04612.5000  0000.8464
04956.2500  0000.8688
05300.0000  0000.8810
05643.7500  0000.8906
05987.5000  0000.9019
06331.2500  0000.9152}

Comment: You might want to use `NonlinearModelFit[]` instead, so that getting the required data is convenient: `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, parameters, x]; Export["filename.dat", Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}], "Table"]`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with nlm, but unfortunately mma was not possible to solve the model as with FindFit, even though according to the documentation it should solve in the same way.
Is it possible to "catch" the calculated values of Findfit in a table and export them?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit[]` uses `FindFit[]` internally, so it doesn't make sense that one works and the other does not. Did you remember to include constraints and starting values? Also, since you included neither your raw data nor your model in your question, I have no way of knowing whether you used it right.

Comment: Of course it doesn't make sense. Maybe you have more insight to my problem right now by adding model, parameter and data. I tried the same constraints and starting values in nlm.

Comment: what are your data exactly? could you please provide an interpretation of the first entry in the list following the text "*[...] Extraction of my data (x,y):*"?

Comment: My data are about absorption (-) over frequency (1/s). That means, first value 00143.7500 = frequency = 143.75 1/s and second value is corresponding absorption 0000.0793 = absorption = 0.0793; next freqeuncy value  is 487.5 and corresponding absorption is 0.2002.
The format with all the 0 is due to Excel export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the data in a *Mathematica* friendly format

```
data = {{143.75, 0.0793}, {487.5, 0.2002}, {831.25, 0.5153}, {1175., 0.8803}, {1518.75, 0.9933}, {1862.5, 0.9361}, {2206.25, 0.8575}, {2550., 0.8051}, {2893.75, 0.7677}, {3237.5, 0.7691}, {3581.25, 0.7717}, {3925., 0.7945}, {4268.75, 0.8263}, {4612.5, 0.8464}, {4956.25, 0.8688}, {5300., 0.881}, {5643.75, 0.8906}, {5987.5, 0.9019}, {6331.25, 0.9152}}
```

The following plot is provided to establish that there were no errors introduced during data import:

> [image: Blockquote]

After evaluating `FindFit` (with a few adjustments due to the way I recoded the various consts etc not really important) the output I obtained was the following:

> [image: Blockquote]

The data and the fitted data are displayed below:

> [image: Blockquote]

Now, since `model/.fit1` evaluates to an expression containing `f`, one way to retrieve the *fitted* values is to evaluate the following:

```
Block[{y},
 (*get the x-coordinates (freqs)*)
 With[{x = Part[data, All, 1]},
  (*replace all occurrences of f in the*fitted*model with the x's*) 
  y = model /. fit1 /. Transpose[{Thread[f -> x]}];
  (*retrieve output*)
  Transpose[{x, y}]
  ]
 ]
```

The following plot is produced using the `Show` from the question by replacing the first `Plot` with `ListPlot`:

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: First, thanks for make some kind of overview of my problem! 
I just have a few questions: 1. Did you use other constraints and/or starting values than mine? 2. I agree with the nice fit between the experimental data and the model and the resulting values, but where exactly do I have to implement the last code with "Block[..]" in my code? 3. Is it then possible to export the fitted values?

Comment: 0. don't mention it! 1. no, I just made `ω` explicitly dependent on `f` (and all associated symbols, too); similarly for `Reff` (dependent on `f` and `α`); I wanted to have expressions with explicit dependencies because that is easier to debug 2. you can evaluate it after `FindFit` evaluates; assuming all goes well it should produce a list of *frequency*-*absorption* pairs 3. Evaluate `Export["fitted.txt",%,"Table"]` after the `Block`.

Comment: Thanks again! But could it be that there is missing a bracket after "Block{..}"?-> Block[{...? and unfortunately there is the following error message: "With: With called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected". Is there missing something after "[..]Thread[f->x]}];" and the next "];" and a second message: "Transpose: The first two levels of {412,y} cannot be transposed"

Comment: please check the *updated* `Block` in the answer; I think it should do the trick, this time... (it was missing the left bracket in `Block` and the comma after the right curly brace in `With`; also, the last `Transpose` contained `x` which was out of scope (`With`))

Comment: Great! Thats exactly the tool I need! Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
fitData = Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], fit6@data[[All, 1]]};

Export["newDataName.txt", fitData]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Is the expression "data" for the genereated data from FindFit or shoud this be a link to my exported data which I also called "data". I ask just to ensure that there is no permutation from mma of my defined imported "data" and some data which are calculated via FindFit.

Comment: data is imported data. Replace txt by dat

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extension of @J.M. 's comment...

What @J.M. showed is how to get predictions (and standard errors) at each data point.  If you don't have too many data points or if those data points are not relatively uniformly dispersed across the range of the predictor values, then you can make predictions on a "grid" of uniformly spaced values (using the first example in `NonlinearModelFit`):

```
(* Run regression *)
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x];

(* Make predictions *)
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data];
n = 100; (* Number of uniformly spaced predictions *)
xx = xmin + (xmax - xmin) Range[0., n]/n;
meanPrediction = nlm[x] /. x -> xx;
mpb = nlm["MeanPredictionBands"] /. x -> xx;
spb = nlm["SinglePredictionBands"] /. x -> xx;

(* Combine into a single expression *)
results = Transpose[{xx, meanPrediction, mpb[[1]], mpb[[2]], spb[[1]],  spb[[2]]}];

(* Export *)
Export["predictions.dat", results, "Table"]
```

This gets you the predictions and the mean and single prediction bands:

```
Show[ListPlot[results[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Blue, Red, Red}, Joined -> True],
 ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: Predictions and prediction bands]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This might be an interesting thing, as far as NLM gives the same result as FindFit, which it should do of course, but in my case it does not.